# How to update null values at Random in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add null values at random to a pandas data for a specific column to perform testing on the data.
For example if i have a dataframe with below values.

| id | total_distance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2000 |
| 3 | 4000 |
| 4 | 5000 |
| 5 | 10000 |

How to pass null values at random like below

| id | total_distance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2000 |
| 3 | 4000 |
| 4 | NaN |
| 5 | 10000 |

Comment: do you need only one nan or any number of random nan in the output?

Comment: Any number of random nan to pass to a dataframe. For example if I have 100 row in a column how do i pass 5 % data with Nan value in that particular column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replace N Rows At Random

[`DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample) is an option.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
                    'total_distance': {0: 1000, 1: 2000,
                                       2: 4000, 3: 5000,
                                       4: 10000}})

# Pull Random Sample N Rows
sample = df1.sample(1)
# Update total_distance column at Sample Index(es)
df1.loc[sample.index, 'total_distance'] = None

print(df1)
```

Possible Output:

```
   id  total_distance
0   1          1000.0
1   1             NaN
2   3          4000.0
3   4          5000.0
4   5         10000.0
```

(The one-liner)

```py
df1.loc[df1.sample(1).index, 'total_distance'] = None
```

---

### Replace Percentage Of Rows At Random

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
                    'total_distance': {0: 1000, 1: 2000,
                                       2: 4000, 3: 5000,
                                       4: 10000}})

# Control Percentage to Replace (45%)
percent_to_replace = .45
# Calc Rows to Sample
row_to_sample = int(len(df1) * percent_to_replace)
# Replace Rows With None
df1.loc[df1.sample(row_to_sample).index, 'total_distance'] = None

print(df1)
```

Possible output:

```
   id  total_distance
0   1          1000.0
1   1             NaN
2   3          4000.0
3   4             NaN
4   5         10000.0
```

(The one-liner)

```py
# Replace 45% of Rows
df1.loc[df1.sample(int(len(df1) * .45)).index, 'total_distance'] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.total_distance.shape, p = [0.5, 0.5])
df['total_distance'] = df.total_distance.mask(mask)
df
```

**Output**

Generated with `np.random.seed(10)`

```
    id  total_distance
0   1   1000.0
1   1   2000.0
2   3   NaN
3   4   5000.0
4   5   NaN
```

**Explanation**.

We are basically creating a numpy boolean mask and placing random nan's in total_distance column

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on those specific df you could just recreate them and replace a value with nan. I might be wrong but its just an idea

```
    database=pd.DataFrame({
   'ID':['1,1,3,4,5'],
   'Total_distance': ['1000, 2000,4000,nan,10000']})

    print(database)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this on column of interest
pd.Series(range(10)).mask(np.random.random(10)<0.5)